# How do I get executor related info from a sparkcontext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark version is 2.3.3. 
I am trying to find total/used memory along with active/total tasks and other executor specific info.

In my driver :-

```
sc.statusTracker.getExecutorInfos.foreach{
      x=>
        x.numRunningTasks()
    }
```

I can get the number of running tasks. But I also need total/used memory from these executors as well. I have thousands of job running on a Yarn cluster. The idea is to get actual usage vs allocated memory so that these can be optimized further.

Update:
http://:8088/proxy//api/v1/applications//executors provides all the information available on UI. Except memory used during computation. Which is what I am looking for majorly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for sc.**getExecutorMemoryStatus**

It return a map from the slave to the max memory available for caching and the remaining memory available for caching.

```
sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus.foreach {
  m => {
    println(s"Slave= ${m._1}")
    println(s"Max Memory Available= ${m._2._1}")
    println(s"Remaining Memory Available= ${m._2._2}")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is memory usage only for caching. Not the actual executor memory usage. I am trying to look for used memory of the container. Computational/Caching or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

All this information can be seen on Spark UI or Spark History server .

There is executors tab in Spark which provides information about the executors and memory allocation, total executors, tasks.

If submitted through YARN ,you can also go through YARN and check the logs it will show the details related to memory allocated to executors.

Comment: I am sorry if I wasnt clear enough in my question, I need these in my application.